# Have achartengine draw on top of the axis

Tags: android, achartengine

As of right now if I have a line chart value that is straight horizontal or vertical and happens to be the exact value as one of the grid lines, then it becomes really tough to see.  Is there any way to change the Z order of how things are drawn such that everything draws over the grid lines?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't such API.
However, you can play with the colors, for instance set some transparency level of the grid lines color, axes color.